# How to fix an app bar that is not center in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, appbar

when ever I open my Reorders page, my app bar title is not center because of the back button so I'm wondering how can I make the app bar to always center like so that it will be the same with other screens.

Any Help or suggestion will be really appreciated.

```
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Maxis",
              style:
                  TextStyle(fontFamily: "Raleway", fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
            ),
            Image.asset(
              "assets/images/maxis.png",
              width: 30,
            ),
            Text(
              "Mobile",
              style:
                  TextStyle(fontFamily: "Raleway", fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
```

You need this inside your Row widget and it'll be centered perfectly.

[image]